# How to create/export custom true type face(.ttf/font) programmatically? - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, core-graphics

I want similar functionality as **iFontMaker** in my application.

User can draw any selected character, modify it and export it.

Can anyone guide me how it will work?

I am doing research but not able to found that how can we export to .ttf.

You can check [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkPRum4NwHs) for more reference.

Thanks in advance.

Appreciate you efforts.

Comment: Have a look at svg and bezier curves as a start. You probably need to create and edit something like that. Your question may be a tad too general and you need to narrow it down and be more specific and show what you tried to get a good response.

Comment: @skaak :- Ok. I will check but can you tell me which class or framework we need to use.
As i describe, when user draw characters, i need to export it as font.

Comment: iFontMaker is not converting fonts on the device directly, its sending the data to a server and responds with a .ttf. But basically iFontMaker is svg & bezier curve editor. [a github php solution to convert svg2ttf](https://github.com/fontello/svg2ttf) another point is if your font will be safe. Because broken (aka wrong formatted) fonts are common thing a glyph validity check is what makes it complex.

Comment: When you use github's search bar you will find plenty of open source projects to look into how its done https://github.com/cdave1/freetype2-ios